# How display images using Imageloader on ImageView from sdcard path?

Tags: android

I have downloaded all images in sdcard from URL. Now I want to display images in GridView using ImageLoader but I am unable to do this.

My image sdcard path like : /mnt/sdcard/DPImages/image_product3.jpg

Comment: Why don't you show us the code that you have tried so far...

Comment: I am facing problem convert sdcard path to Bitmap my code:       Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bean.get_productSDCardPath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);                                        I am getting null

Answer (score 1):

```
private String[] mFileStrings;
private File[] listFile;   

public void getFromSdcard()
{
   File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"DPImages");//sdcard/DpImages

        if (file.isDirectory())//if files is directory
        {
            listFile = file.listFiles();
            mFileStrings = new String[listFile.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
            {
                mFileStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();//mFileStrings with uri of images

            }
        }
}
```

You can use the mFileStrings to display the images in gridview.

In your getView of adapter.

```
        ImageView image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFileStrings[position]);
        image.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using universal image downloader.

You can show the image with this:

```
String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card

imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

The link is this. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader